# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1

Tags: wordpress

Still getting this error message in debug mode despite trying the following: manually deleting and replacing the wp-includes and wp-admin directories. Renamed the plugins directory, Updating the class-http.php file as per https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-http.php, imported a backup of sql tables (a couple of years old) in MYSQL

Deprecated: File class-http.php is deprecated since version 5.9.0! Use wp-includes/class-wp-http.php instead. in /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5569

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_enable_block_templates' not found or invalid function name in /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 307

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_schedule_https_detection' not found or invalid function name in /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 307

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_allowed_block_template_part_areas() in /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-includes/blocks/template-part.php:168 Stack trace: #0 /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-includes/blocks/template-part.php(194): build_template_part_block_variations() #1 /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): register_block_core_template_part('') #2 /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #3 /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4 /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-settings.php(557): do_action('init') #5 /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-config.php(92): require_once('/home2/dvinegri...') #6 /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home2/dvinegri...') #7 /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home2/dvinegri...') #8 /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/index.php(17): require( in /home2/dvinegrindz/public_html/wpr/wp-includes/blocks/template-part.php on line 168

Answer (score 0):

The message says that you point to class-http.php in your functions.php on line 5569.

class-http.php is deprecated so no longer supported and you have to replace it with wp-includes/class-wp-http.php

So look in your functions.php where you point to class-http.php (should be line 5569) and replace it ... point to the new file wp-includes/class-wp-http.php

Comment: if ( function_exists( '__' ) ) {
   if ( $replacement ) {
    trigger_error(
     sprintf(
      /* translators: 1: PHP file name, 2: Version number, 3: Alternative file name. */
      __( 'File %1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! Use %3$s instead.' ),
      $file,
      $version,
      $replacement
     ) . $message,
     E_USER_DEPRECATED
    ); - line 5569 is E_USER_DEPRECATED

Comment: Ok this sadly say nothing to me :-( I think there is some more damaged in the core of wp I would try to make a new setup of wp and then first only import the post and Page data from the old wp ... move along part for part (install plugins and so on) till you get errors .. maybe test on a local environment like xampp portable ... I think here would lead one error to a other so it's like search a needle in the hay :-(

Comment: If there are non sensitiv data in the old wp copy I can try to implement it if you would send it over ... but no guarantees..